# Add zero padding to string using $"{x:Dn}" notation

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I am a big fan of the new $"" notation to format strings in c#. Hence I would like to use this notation to pre-pend some leading zero's to an integer.

```
var i = 10;
var s = $"{i:D4}";
```

This does the job well en results in 0010.

But what if the amount of zero's or the total length is variable. How do I accomplish that using this new notation ?

I'm looking for somthing like :

```
var TotalLength = 4; // IRL it would be a calculated value.
var format = "D" + TotalLength.ToString();
var i = 10;
var s = $"{i:format}";
```

variant I've tried but does not work either.

```
$"{i:{format}}"
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can try this: `var s = $"{i.ToString().PadLeft(totalLength, '0')}";`

Comment: Or: `var s = i.ToString(new string('0', totalLength))`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions given I've made two extension methods :

```
     public static String GetDnFormat(this int i)
    {
        return ((int)Math.Log10(i) + 1).ToString("'D'0");
    }

    public static String ToDnFormat(this int i, int source)
    {
        var format = source.GetDnFormat();
        return i.ToString(format);
    }
```

Usage :

```
var Page = 10;
var PageCount = 124;
var PageLabel = $"{Page.ToDnFormat(PageCount)}/{PageCount}"; // result : 010/124
```

Answer (score 0):

Or - mixing your *something like* and Rob's method:

```
var TotalLength = 4; // IRL it would be a calculated value.
var format = TotalLength.ToString("'D'0");
var i = 10;
var s = $"{i.ToString(format)}";
```